# Partition a column based on missing values

Tags: python, pandas, partitioning

How would I go about partitioning a column based on missing value in python.

I have have the following table in a dataframe:

```
Store      Bag 
Alberts    ClothBag
Vons       KateSpade
Ralphs     GroceryBag1
Na         apple
Na         pear
Na         staples
Kmart      ShoppingList
Na         beachball
Na         milk
QuikEmart  List5 
Na         Duff
Na         Donuts
```

And based on the NA's or any other way, how would I reproduce the following table:

```
Store      Bag              Item
Alberts    ClothBag         ClothBag
Vons       KateSpade        KateSpade
Ralphs     GroceryBag1      apple
Na         GroceryBag1      pear 
Na         GroceryBag1      staples     
Kmart      ShoppingList     beachball
Na         ShoppingList     milk
QuikEmart  List5            Duff
Na         List5            Dounuts
```

If there are no Na's beneath the store then the item column will assume the name of the Bag, as shown in the first two columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(d):
    if len(d) > 1:
        r = d.iloc[1:]
        r['Item'] = r['Bag']
        r['Bag'] = d.Bag.iat[0]
        r['Store'].iat[0] = d.Store.iat[0]
        return r
    else:
        return d.assign(Item=d.Bag)

df.groupby(df.Store.ne('Na').cumsum(), group_keys=False).apply(f)

        Store           Bag       Item
0     Alberts      ClothBag   ClothBag
1        Vons     KateSpade  KateSpade
3      Ralphs   GroceryBag1      apple
4          Na   GroceryBag1       pear
5          Na   GroceryBag1    staples
7       Kmart  ShoppingList  beachball
8          Na  ShoppingList       milk
10  QuikEmart         List5       Duff
11         Na         List5     Donuts
```

Comment: hi piRsquared, thanks for taking the time to help out, but I believe there is an issue in the code where, when ran, Bag and Item column are identical.